# How to get local folder name with AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I need to browse to a folder to get the directory name by clicking a button, is there any way of getting this? I was thinking I could achieve this by using `<input type="file" />`

Comment: If you want server side answers, add `nodejs` and `fileserver` to your tags.

Answer (score 3):

For security reasons you cant. You can get just the file name, the rest is handled by the browser.

Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15201258/1248388

More documentation on the File API https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: Well, I have a issue that i want to read all csv/xls file from a folder and then cut paste to another folder. For this reason i need the path of From Folder and To Folder. I can do it directly texting but if there any way to browse it by a button click from my pc or any pc connected by network server with mine?

Comment: Or is there any way from server side i get the full folder path (N.B. need folder path actually not the file) ?